# Trying to launch minecraft but getting "Open with" menu

Tags: java, minecraft, launcher, javaw

I have been working on  minecraft launcher for quite sometime now and I am starting to get a problem that I have never seen before. In earlier version of my launcher I was able to successfully launch minecraft 1.8, but now with the same exact code when launcher the same version I am getting the "open with" dialog for the javaw.exe, which sounds a little strange to me because windows is asking how to open an exe file with. But here is the code I am working with:

```
    private void StartMinecraftOP()
    {
        string installPath = GetJavaInstallationPath();
        string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(installPath, "bin\\Javaw.exe");

        string appData = "C:\\.JamPacked";
        string directory = ".minecraft";
        ProcessStartInfo mcStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("javaw.exe", "-Xms256m -Xmx1024m" +
        " -Djava.library.path=\"" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\versions\\1.8.7-OptiFine_HD_U_D6\\1.8.7-OptiFine_HD_U_D6-natives\"" + " -cp \"" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\net\\minecraft\\launchwrapper\\1.7\\launchwrapper-1.7.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\oshi-project\\oshi-core2\\1.1\\oshi-core-1.1.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\net\\java\\dev\\jna\\jna\\3.4.0\\jna-3.4.0.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\net\\java\\dev\\jna\\platform\\3.4.0\\platform-3.4.0.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\com\\ibm\\icu\\icu4j-core-mojang\\51.2\\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\net\\sf\\jopt-simple\\jopt-simple\\4.6\\jopt-simple-4.6.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\com\\paulscode\\codecjorbis\\20101023\\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\com\\paulscode\\codecwav\\20101023\\codecwav-20101023.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\com\\paulscode\\libraryjavasound\\20101123\\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\com\\paulscode\\librarylwjglopenal\\20100824\\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\com\\paulscode\\soundsystem\\20120107\\soundsystem-20120107.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\io\\netty\\netty-all\\4.0.23.Final\\netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\com\\google\\guava\\guava\\17.0\\guava-17.0.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\org\\apache\\commons\\commons-lang3\\3.3.2\\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\commons-io\\commons-io\\2.4\\commons-io-2.4.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\commons-codec\\commons-codec\\1.9\\commons-codec-1.9.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\net\\java\\jinput\\jinput\\2.0.5\\jinput-2.0.5.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\net\\java\\jutils\\jutils\\1.0.0\\jutils-1.0.0.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\com\\google\\code\\gson\\gson\\2.2.4\\gson-2.2.4.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\com\\mojang\\authlib\\1.5.21\\authlib-1.5.21.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\com\\mojang\\realms\\1.7.23\\realms-1.7.23.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\org\\apache\\commons\\commons-compress\\1.8.1\\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\org\\apache\\httpcomponents\\httpclient\\4.3.3\\httpclient-4.3.3.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\commons-logging\\commons-logging\\1.1.3\\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\org\\apache\\httpcomponents\\httpcore\\4.3.2\\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\org\\apache\\logging\\log4j\\log4j-core\\2.0-beta9\\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\org\\lwjgl\\lwjgl\\lwjgl\\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\\lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\org\\lwjgl\\lwjgl\\lwjgl_util\\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\\lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\org\\lwjgl\\lwjgl\\lwjgl-platform\\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\\lwjgl-platform-2.9.4-nightly-20150209-natives-windows.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\net\\java\\jinput\\jinput-platform\\2.0.5\\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\tv\\twitch\\twitch\\6.5\\twitch-6.5.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\tv\\twitch\\twitch-platform\\6.5\\twitch-platform-6.5-natives-windows-64.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\tv\\twitch\\twitch-external-platform\\4.5\\twitch-external-platform-4.5-natives-windows-64.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\libraries\\optifine\\OptiFine\\1.8.7_HD_U_D6\\OptiFine-1.8.7_HD_U_D6.jar;" +
              appData + "\\" + directory + "\\versions\\1.8.7-OptiFine_HD_U_D6\\1.8.7-OptiFine_HD_U_D6.jar\" " +
              "net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch " + "--tweakClass optifine.OptiFineTweaker " +
              "--username " + project_source_launcher.Program.Globals._username +
              " --accessToken " + project_source_launcher.Program.Globals._accesstoken +
              " --version 1.8.7-OptiFine_HD_U_D6" +
              " --gameDir " + appData + "\\" + directory +
              " --assetsDir " + appData + "\\" + directory + "\\assets" +
              " --userProperties {}" +
              " --uuid " + project_source_launcher.Program.Globals._UUID);

        Process.Start(mcStartInfo);
```

Once I click the launch button I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/osDeo.jpg
And in advance thanks for the help.

Comment: With such a long command line you may be hitting the max command line length (only 8192 chars).  There is a trick you can do to pass a long library path on Windows, namely to create a JAR that contains only a manifest declaring the paths you want, and add only that jar. see [`FileUtil.createJarWithClassPath`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html)

Comment: I only got 5166 characters when I counted the contents of ProcessStartInfo(...).

Comment: @Jamriz21 The 'open with' dialog only displays for 'javaw.exe', correct?

Comment: @Speerian yes only for the javaw.exe.

Comment: @RemusRusanu while you bring up a good point I have had command lines that are very similar to this one (to launch other versions of the game) working before, that being said I tried those to see if I messed up on making this one and it happen for the ones that worked perfectly so I don't know if it is just something with this computer's java installation or there is something in java that has changed or something, but thanks for the info, I didn't know there was a limit.